# Мониторинг telegram каналов

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, chat, monit

Сейчас этот код выводит в терминал сообщения пользователей из указанного канала в реальном времени, иногда почему то с ошибками, но выводит. Но мне надо перенаправить их в мой бот, но бот ничего не воспринимает, чат id я указывал. Код начинает немного работать если указать свой личный чат, на котором создан api id и api кэш, но потом снова выходят ошибки, о не существующим id чата.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 00000000
api_hash = "#######################"
phone = "+7000000000"

# Создаем клиент Telegram
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def monitor_messages():
    # Определяем ключевые слова, по которым будем фильтровать сообщения
    ключевые_слова = ['ищу', "работа"]

    # Задаем список названий каналов для мониторинга
    целевые_каналы = ['КЛИЕНТЫ || РАБОТА ОНЛАЙН']

    @client.on(events.NewMessage)
    async def handler(event):
        try:
            if event.is_channel and event.chat.title in целевые_каналы:
                for ключ in ключевые_слова:
                    if ключ.lower() in event.raw_text.lower():
                        имя_отправителя = event.sender.username if event.sender else "Нет имени пользователя"
                        print(f'Новое сообщение в канале {event.chat.title}:')
                        print(f'{имя_отправителя} написал(а): {event.raw_text}')
                        # Можно выполнить дополнительные действия с сообщением
        except Exception as e:
            if "AuthKeyUnregisteredError" not in str(e):
                print(e)

    print("Старт мониторинга сообщений...")
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

async def main():
    # Запускаем мониторинг сообщений в фоновом режиме
    await monitor_messages()

# Запускаем клиент Telegram и основную программу
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```